# Not able to render map from WMS to MapInfo using MapXtreme

Tags: wms, mapinfo, mapxtreme

I am trying to get the map from WMS which is hosted on GeoServer to the map. I am getting the layer of WMS but I am not able to display in the Map Screen. Here is my code to do so:

```
ICapabilities capablities = MapInfo.Wms.WmsClientUtilities.GetCapabilities("http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/Jonathan/wms?", "1.1.1");
 MapInfo.Wms.WmsClient wmsClient = new MapInfo.Wms.WmsClient(capablities);
int chartCount = wmsClient.Capabilities.RootLayer.Layers.Count();
wmsClient.AddLayer(wmsClient.Capabilities.RootLayer.Layers[4].Title);
wmsClient.Srs = wmsClient.Capabilities.RootLayer.Layers[4].Bounds[0].Srs;
wmsClient.MimeType = wmsClient.MimeType;
wmsClient.BGColor = Color.White;

MapInfo.Data.TableInfoWms wmsTableInfo = new MapInfo.Data.TableInfoWms("MywmsTable", wmsClient);
Table wmsTable = Session.Current.Catalog.OpenTable(wmsTableInfo);
FeatureLayer featLyr = new FeatureLayer(wmsTable);
MapInfo.Mapping.Map map = MapInfo.Engine.Session.Current.MapFactory.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\MapInfo\Data\Introductory Data\World\WORLD.TAB", System.IntPtr.Zero, System.Drawing.Size.Empty);  

map.Layers.Add(featLyr);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: is there any error message? can you look on the server and see the GeoServer log? if so what (if any) error messages are there?

Comment: No there is no error from geoserver side. i am thinking I am doing something wrong while add layer in Mapinfo

Comment: See https://onegeology-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/portal.html#using-mapinfo-professional for details on adding WMS to MapInfo